# $\text{Var}((W_t-W_s)^2)=2(t-s)^2$.

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

I recently started learning about Brownian motions/Wiener processes. I was reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/304678/340973) to understand what is the variance of the square of the increments of a Brownian motion. In the post, it is computed as

> $$\text{Var}((W_t-W_s)^2) = \text{Var}(W_{t-s}^2) =
>  \mathbb{E}\left[(W_{t-s}^2-(t-s))^2 \right] \stackrel{\ast}{=} (t-s)^2
>  \cdot \underbrace{\mathbb{E}((W_1^2-1)^2)}_{2} = 2(t-s)^2.$$

However, I don't understand what trick the person answering used to say directly that $\text{Var}((W_t-W_s)^2) = \text{Var}(W_{t-s}^2)$ and also $\mathbb{E}((W_1^2-1)^2) = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

1. $\mathbb V\left[\left(W_t-W_s\right)^2\right] = \mathbb V\left[W_{t-s}^2\right]$ because the Brownian motion has stationary increments.
2. $\mathbb E\left[\left(W_1^2-1\right)^2\right] = 2$ because $W_1^2\sim\chi(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't get how you deduce the expectation of $(W_1^2-1)^2$ just by knowing that $W_1^2$ has a chi-square distribution. Just to be sure, stationary increments means that the distribution of $W_t-W_s$ has the same distribution as $W_{t-s}$?